# How do I Truncate middle of String based on conditions in UILabel in Swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, string, uilabel, truncate

I have a String like this :
AU 6,7,8,9,10,11,...,20,21,22,23,24,25
[refer this image](https://ibb.co/K9tqWR5)

I have to fill only 8 sizes. This sizes have no limit they can be more than 20 or 50 also.
If there are only 8 sizes available, show AU 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ,13
If there are more than 8 sizes, show AU 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ... 25. Three dots in front of the last size only.

I have given 1 number of lines to the UILabel and Link Break is Truncate Middle.

I'm very new to swift and I have no idea how do I achieve this ? I would be grateful for your help. Thank You !

Comment: What do you mean by "fill 8 characters"? "AU 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ,13" has a lot more characters than 8. Also, what happens when there are less than 8 sizes?

Comment: I have to show only 8 characters in UILabel like this : AU 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ,13 (I meant 8 Numbers except AU, 6,7,8, etc are sizes, and I only have to show 8 sizes)
if more than 8 sizes then show AU 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ... 25. Three dots in front of the last size only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the requirement is not achievable by means on SwiftUI only. An algorithm that generates a string out of an array of sizes (integers) should help. For instance:

```swift
func makeSizesString(sizesArray: [Int]) -> String {
  if (sizesArray.count <= 8) {
    sizesArray.map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: ", ")
  } else {
    sizesArray[...5].map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: ", ") + " ... \(sizesArray[sizesArray.count - 1])"
  }
}

print(makeSizesString(sizesArray: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])) // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
print(makeSizesString(sizesArray: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])) // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
print(makeSizesString(sizesArray: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])) // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ... 9
print(makeSizesString(sizesArray: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])) // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ... 10
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Really appreciate your time. Thank You!

Comment: NP. Happy coding.